# How to create multiple waypoints (Openui5-googlemaps)?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am helping in a project which the goal is to read a .json file with destinations, rendering a map with the route generated.

I am using the library from jasper07 (this guy made something awesome):
https://github.com/jasper07/openui5-googlemaps

i added the library without problems, everything runs as supposed to, the data binding is ok, but it only reads 1 waypoint, in my xml view i have a "gmap:Directions" with the start and end point, and i have the gmap:Waypoint (which will represent a stopover).

How to make my code generate more Waypoint tags based on the quantity of wayppoint objects in the .json file?

My view:

```
<mvc:View 
    xmlns="sap.m" 
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" 
    xmlns:gmaps="openui5.googlemaps"
    controllerName="project1.controller.Mapa">
    <Page id="page" title="{i18n>title}">
        <IconTabBar
        id="idIconTabBarStretchContent"
        stretchContentHeight="true"
        backgroundDesign="Transparent"
        applyContentPadding="false"
        expanded="{device>/isNoPhone}"
        class="sapUiResponsiveContentPadding">
            <items>
                <IconTabFilter id="produtos" text="Produtos" key="products">
                    <Text id="haha" text="Lista de produtos ..." />
                </IconTabFilter>
                <IconTabFilter id="centros" text="Centros" key="centers">
                    <Text id="haha2" text="Centros listados aqui ..." />
                </IconTabFilter>
                <IconTabFilter id="rotas" text="Rotas" key="routes">
                    <content>
                        <gmaps:Map id="gmap" height="500px" zoom="12" lat="-29.76028" lng="-51.14722" 
                        apiKey="">
                            <gmaps:directions>
                                <gmaps:Directions 
                                                startAddress="{waypoints>/directions/startAddress}" 
                                                endAddress="{waypoints>/directions/endAddress}">
                                    <gmaps:waypoints>
                                        <gmaps:Waypoint id="parada" location="{waypoints>/waypoint/0/location}"    stopover= "{waypoints>/waypoint/0/stopover}"/>
                                    </gmaps:waypoints>
                                </gmaps:Directions>
                            </gmaps:directions>
                        </gmaps:Map>
                    </content>
                </IconTabFilter>    
            </items>
        </IconTabBar>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

My controller:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
],
    /**
     * @param {typeof sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller} Controller
     */
    function (Controller, JSONModel) {
        "use strict";

        return Controller.extend("project1.controller.Mapa", {
            onInit: function () {
            // Modelo JSON
            var oModel = new JSONModel();
            oModel.loadData("../model/Itinerario.json");
            console.log(oModel);           

            // Disponibiliza model na view que estiver sendo exibida
            this.getView().setModel(oModel, "waypoints");
        }});
    });
```

The .json file:

```
{   
    "directions" :
    {
        "id_direcoes": 1,
        "startAddress": "São Leopoldo, RS",
        "endAddress": "Porto Alegre, RS",
        "travelMode": "",
        "optimizeWaypoints": "",
        "unitSystem": ""
    },
    "waypoint" :[
    {
        "id_parada": 1,
        "location": "Sapucaia do Sul, RS",
        "stopover": true
    },
    {
        "id_parada": 2,
        "location": "Esteio, RS",
        "stopover": true
    }]
}
```

The map on screen
[The points A and C are from the Directions tag, and the B point is from the Waypoints tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvCHY.png)

I tried to access the attributes of the tags from the controller to make some kind of a loop over the json file with JS, but it didnt work, then i thought i needed some scripting to create new tags by naming the object name in the "location" attribute from the waypoints tag, but it didnt work also, i am a begginer with openui5 so i didnt have any other ideas...